# How to get an 100vw item to be centred when inside a container that is not centred and not full width?

Tags: html, css

I have a full width element inside a container that is not full width (715px). This container is not centred as it's got a side bar next to it (245px).

I cannot absolutely position the item as it's dynamic / a block in a matrix.

How can I ensure that it is always centre no matter what screen size?

`margin: auto`
`margin-left: 50%`

don't work, using a percentage and doing it visually doesn't work because as soon as the screen size changes the full width element is no longer centred

HTML

```
<section class="grid">
    <div class="grid__item one-quarter">
        <ul>
            <li>List Item</li>
            <li>List Item</li>
            <li>List Item</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
        <div class="grid__item three-quarters">
            <div class="page-builder-item">
                <h1>Some content in an element</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="page-builder-item">
                <h1>Some content in an element</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="page-builder-item full-width">
                <h1>Some content in an FULL WIDTH element</h1>
            </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.grid {
    width: 960px;
    display: flex;
    margin: auto;
}

.grid-item {
    display: inline-block;

}

.one-quarter {
    width: 25%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.three-quarters {
    width: 75%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.page-builder-item {
    background: pink;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}

.page-builder-item.full-width {
    width: 100vw;
    background: magenta;
    margin-left: -25%;
}
```

Link to codepen example https://codepen.io/hellojessicagraham/pen/pxedav

Comment: post a working snippet of what you have

Comment: This page is quite inspiring: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Comment: @PoulBak thanks for this! the parent container is not centred though. Also items are dynamic so can't be positioned absolute as they can appear in any order or not at all

Comment: There has _got_ to be a better way to layout your content. That full width content will intersect the sidebar list items if it gets longer. Just my 2 cents. Otherwise, the solution by Hofma Dresu is pretty much the easiest way around this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

Generally I think it's best to keep children elements within the bounds of their parents because of how tricky this can get. However if you need to use this layout you can try something like:

```
margin-left: calc((-1 * 960px * .25) - (50vw - (.5 * 960px)));
```

I'm sure that can be shortened, but I wanted to leave the full calculation in place for clarity's sake. The first part, `-1 * 960px *.25` moves the magenta box to align its left edge with the grid's left edge. The second part `50vw - (.5 * 960px)` then moves the magenta box further so that its left edge aligns with the browser's left edge.

The problem with this is it's somewhat brittle. It depends *very* heavily on the exact width of both the 'grid' element and the percent width of the left column.

[CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/full-width-containers-limited-width-parents/) has a good post about centering items that are wider than their parents. It's solutions don't directly apply to this case, but it's a good resource to better understand your options and I used it to develop the calc statement I used